# Does a JSON file on disk, occupy the same amount of space when loaded into a var in memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I store some JSON files on disk (each very small about 4kB), and load them into a var when required.
I may have thousands of such files, and if the space they occupy in memory is the same as what they occupy on disk, I would rather load them all into memory at application start.

How can I calculate how much memory (RAM) the file occupies when I create an object from it ?

EDIT: I know how to save JSON files to disk. That is not my question. I am trying to understand how much memory (RAM), a JSON file will occupy when I load it into a var. **If I know the size of the JSON file on disk, how can I calculate how much memory (RAM) it will occupy when I create a javascript object from the file in node.js or in a web browser ?**

The files are saved as "plain text files".
Eg:

```
{"foo": {
    "bar": 1,
    "foo": {
        "bar": [
            "foo",
            "bar"
        ], 
        "foo":[
             "bar",
             "foo"
        ]
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: please have a look 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202645/how-do-i-store-json-data-on-a-disk

Comment: That is not relevant to my question. I know how to store data on disk. I'm trying to understand, how much memory a given JSON file will occupy in memory, and how to measure it.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of RAM occupied by the object is not the same as the size of the file. The size of the file is simply the number of bytes in it, but the amount of RAM occupied by the object depends on the values stored in it. For example, in an object like this:

```
{
    "bar": 1
}
```

When saved to a file, `1` is only a single byte. However, if you were to load this object into a `var`, `1` would occupy 8 bytes, since it is a `number`.

Take a look at this answer for the size of each datatype: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11900218/1611665

Also, you should take the size of the keys into account (but that's pretty simple, it's twice as much as the `length` property if your keys are strings).

Comment: So based on the code in the  question you linked to, my 4KB JSON file, seems to become a 3748 byte object. Weird coincidence. Thanks for the explanation. But can you explain what you mean by taking the size of the keys into account ? Do you mean that I should because th e other code sample does not ?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see any of the other examples taking the size of the keys into account, even though the keys occupy RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to measure memory consumption in the JavaScript execution environment you use.
E.g.for the chrome browser, you can use this [memory profiling guide](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling).

Your mentioning of data files suggests that your code runs on the server, probably node.js. 
I would have a look at [this](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-heap-profiling-tip/).